# Jenkins: launch script to remote slave and get results

Tags: jenkins

It is the first time to jenkins, I apologize in advance if I cannot be precise in terms...
I need run tests to ec2 slave and get result to jenkins, the test file is to git, every time I do a commit, I have to run a job on jenkins.

I've create a slave and work and I've planned to use hooks to git for launch a build, but do not understand how I can run the script, is a php file. Should I use maven ? I have to copy the script on the master machine? How does it work?
Thanks to anyone who wants to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Jenkins [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), in particular the section ***[Push notification from repository](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Pushnotificationfromrepository)***:

> To minimize the delay between a push and a build, it is recommended to set up the post-receive hook in the repository to poke Jenkins when a new push occurs.

To execute scripts add a build step ***Build** → [**Execute shell**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shells) → Command* to your job.

#### UPDATE

See [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin):

> You can use the SSH Plugin to run shell commands on a remote machine via ssh.

Or you could:

- make your remote machine a [Jenkins slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) and tie your job(s) to this slave node via:

  ***Meta Data** → Restrict where this project can be run* or
- assign label(s) to your master and slave(s) nodes via:

  *Manage Jenkins → Manage Nodes* (`http://<your jenkins>/computer`) → [image] → *Labels*

  to establish more flexible associations: job → label(s) → node(s).

Comment: Ok for hook file...but how can launch a script to remote machine? maybe just run it locally and automatically jenkins throws remotely ? and output ? also to receive automatically in jenkins ?